# Error : Operation not allowed without an active reactive context

Tags: r, shiny

I am writing a Shiny App which essentially looks like below in nutshell :

```
ui <- fluidPage(

  fluidRow(
    column(6,  sliderInput("obs", "Input", min = 0, max = 1000, value = 500)),
    column(6, plotOutput(outputId = "plot2", height = "600px")))


  )

server <- function(input, output) {
  Input = reactive({
      Data = input$obs
      Data1 = ifelse(Data < 500, '1', '0')
      return(list(Data = Data, Data1 = Data1))
  })

  if (Input()$Data1 == '1') {
          output$plot2 = renderPlot(plot(1:5))
  } else {
          output$plot2 = renderPlot(plot(1:50))
  }

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

However when I run this code, I got error which reads like

> Error in .getReactiveEnvironment()$currentContext() : 
>     Operation not allowed without an active reactive context. (You tried to do something that can only be done from inside a reactive expression or observer.)

Looks like something must be wrong with `if (Input()$Data1 == '1')`, However I could not figure out where it is wrong.

Comment: well you call `Input()` while defining it. Replace  ´Input()$Data1` with `Data1` and it should work,..

Comment: Hi  BigDataScientist, I dont think this is happening. The condition 'Input()$Data1 == '1'' is definitely outside Input(), please check the closure of curly bracket for Input() definition

Comment: well you are right. Would be good to change the formatting, its hard to read otherwise. You can solve your error then by wrapping the part `if (Input()$Data1 == '1') {....}` in an `observe()` function. That is the reactive environment "he" is asking for.

Comment: Thanks, this is working